# Trying to add a vertex with property violates uniqueness constraint despite property value is not yet present

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin

I have a graph that has vertices with a property called `fbid` and I created an index for that with a uniqueness constraint. Initialization of the graph (installing the schema and adding some initial vertices and edges) happened using Java code that I added to the Titan libraries and that I manually trigger in the gremlin shell:

```
gremlin> :> com.my.example.TestGraphFactory.loadScheme(graph)
gremlin> :> com.my.example.TestGraphFactory.loadGraph(graph)
```

Now, I am trying to do this:

```
gremlin> :> g.V().has('fbid', 'fbid_42')
gremlin> :> g.V().addV(label, 'user').property('fbid', 'fbid_42')
Adding this property for key [fbid] and value [fbid_42] violates a uniqueness constraint [fbid]
Display stack trace? [yN] y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: Adding this property for key [fbid] and value [fbid_42] violates a uniqueness constraint [fbid]
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:116)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.commands.SubmitCommand.execute(SubmitCommand.groovy:41)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.execute(Shell.groovy:101)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.super$2$execute(Groovysh.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.executeCommand(Groovysh.groovy:254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:153)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:144)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
```

I don't see the reason for this since this is virtually the first action I take after establishing the scheme and initializing the graph with some first vertices and edges (none of them with this particular property value).

Where should I look?

Comment: Can you post the code for `loadScheme` and `loadGraph`?

Comment: Both did not cause the problem. I made a mistake in the request statement. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason lies here:

```
gremlin> :> g.V().addV(label, 'user').property('fbid', 'fbid_42')
```

I was too blind to see that I do a request to obtain all vertices before trying to add the new vertex. The correct request would thus be

```
gremlin> :> g.addV(label, 'user').property('fbid', 'fbid_42')
```